# Find all angles between $0$ and $180$ degree's such that $tan(\theta)=-16$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Find all angles between $0$ and $180$ degrees such that $\tan(\theta)=-16.$

I've been working on this problem for days and can't figure it out!! Need a fresh perspective, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such an angle must fall in the second quadrant -- in other words, it must be obtuse. Then just take the arctangent to get $$180°+\arctan(-16)=180°-\arctan(16)$$

Comment: I think this is the most direct answer. The function $\arctan(x)$ is defined to give results in the first quadrant for positive $x$ and the fourth quadrant for negative $x.$ But the tangent of an angle is $x$ when the angle is $\arctan(x)$ plus any integer multiple of $180$ degrees. Moreover, in degrees the fourth-quadrant result is in the range from $-90$ to $0.$ so to get it into the range $0$ to $180,$ it is necessary and sufficient to add $180.$

Comment: are there typo's in this?

Comment: @MathematicalMushroom No, I've checked again. What looks like a typo?

Answer (score 0):

For a fresh perspective think of the tangent as the gradient of the half line rotating about the origin.
I think there should be an angle between 90 and 180. This is because the gradient of the half line is negative there.  Likewise in quadrant 4 too. Note your calc will not give this directly only the principle value.

Answer (score 0):

The reference angle is $\arctan 16 \approx 86.42^{\circ}$. The tangent is positive in the first quadrant but negative in the second, so the only solution is $180^{\circ} - 86.42^{\circ}=93.58^{\circ}$.